# Tkinter Text Widget : Retrieve the first character of a line

Tags: text, indexing, tkinter, widget, character

I have a Text widget that has the text :

```
    This is some random text
```

As you can see, the first "T" of the text is at `1.4`. With different text, how can I retrieve the index of first character in each line. Any help is highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a function that returns the index of the first non space character of a string:

```
def get_index(txt):
    l = txt.split(" ")
    i = 0
    while i < len(l) and l[i] == "":
        i += 1
    if i == len(l):
        # the string is empty or contains only spaces
        return -1
    else:
        return i
```

And then apply this to each line contained in your Text widget.

Comment: I don't think returning -1 is a good idea. Because in Python it is a valid index (last element). It might be cleaner to raise some exception to be caught when the function is called

Comment: I agree, but if it raises an error you have to use `try` or check the string first, maybe returning None could be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

No need to define functions of your own, when built-in tools can do the job for you.

Use the `lstrip` method to remove spaces on the left. Then take the first character. And use the `index` method to retrieve the index of that character.

```
text = '     hello'
c = text.lstrip()[0]  # c : 'h'
idx = text.index(c)  # idx : 5
```

`lstrip` can take as an argument any piece of string you want to cut out, default is space. You may also be interested in `rstrip` (same on the right side) and `strip` (on both sides)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know about that

Comment: But what if I want to retrieve the index of that letter? What should I do?

Comment: Just be aware that this gets and error if you get a string `'    \n'`

Comment: This kind of operation obviously needs to be used inside a try/except block, because you are indexing some string you know nothing about.

Comment: But it's a Text widget, you cannot use `lstrip` for it. I need to return the index of the first letter in the Text Widget

Comment: Just do this on the text of your Text widget. Use the `get` method to retrieve the text as a string, and apply this method.